# Why am I getting different behavior in Safari and Chrome with flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am displaying a row of images.  Here is my `html`:

```
<div class="flex">
  <img src="img1.jpg"/>
  <img src="img2.jpg"/>
  <img src="img3.jpg"/>
  <img src="img4.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Here is my `css`:

```
.flex {
  display: flex
}

img {
  height: auto;
}
```

I want my images to display in a row.  I have not given the `img`s any width, so on `Chrome` the `img`s take up their natural width and push out bigger than then screen. This is how I want it to work.   With `Safari`, they `flexbox` will only take up the full `viewport` width.  I have tried setting an image width, flex-basis, but cannot make `Safari` use more than just the visible screen.  Is there a `flexbox` issue that I don't know about?  What else can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this is a bug in Safari. Try adding `flex-shrink: 0` to `img`.

```
img {
    height: auto;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

With webkit prefix to support older Safari browsers -- I'd add it to `.flex` too as james suggests (note to self: upgrade Safari).

Comment: I would like the complete opposite, in other words i would better have the Safari bug in all browsers. How would it possible to recreate it in other browsers? Any ideas? Desired behaviour : The items are stuck between the borders of the viewport and get closer to eachother when resizing to a smaller viewport.

Answer (score 0):

I think safari needs the -webkit options for it to work. e.g.

```
.flex {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
}

img {
  height: auto;
}
```

This is the same for all options. e.g.

```
justify-content: center;
-webkit-justify-content: center;
align-items: stretch;
-webkit-align-items: stretch;
```

This page is a nice reference source for flexbox:

http://www.sketchingwithcss.com/samplechapter/cheatsheet.html

Comment: That didn't fix the problem.  It still looks the same.